# Scaling Socket.IO on Loopback

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, loopbackjs, strongloop

I have a Loopback application with a Socket.IO server attached.

This works perfectly when am running one process, but as soon as I try to scale it vertically, Socket.IO can no longer be connected to failing with 400 Bad Request

I have done research and found a lot of recommendations of using sticky-sessions such as node-cluster-socket.io.

Has anyone successfully scaled a Loopback application running Socket.IO? How did you do it?

Comment: Ages ago before when node was v0.6 I used to maintain a multiprocess socket.io app. I got this worked by using the redis store which is now this I think: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-redis , this might fix your problem.

Comment: Btw, this is not much related to loopback as loopback will just set some routes on express from socket.io point of view. So any solution that works with express and socket.io should work with your setup.